# Simple form submit button not working when inside content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I have created this form in rails using simple form with bootstrap:

```
<%= simple_form_for @page, :html => { :class => 'page-form' } do |f| %>
<div class="row">

    <%= f.input :title, wrapper_html: { class: 'span6'}  %>
    <%= f.input :url, wrapper_html: { class: 'span3'}  %>
    <%= f.input :content, input_html: { class: 'wysihtml5 span9' }, wrapper_html: { class: 'span9 row' } %>
    <%= f.input :excerpt, input_html: { class: 'wysihtml5 span9 excerpt' }, wrapper_html: { class: 'span9 row'}  %>

</div>

<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Publish</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <%= f.input :status , collection: Page::STATUS.map { |s| [s.humanize, s] }, prompt: '- Select page status -' %>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                    pages_path, :class => 'btn' %>
      </div>
  </div>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

The problem is that when the submit button is inside the `content_for` block it does not update the form when clicked. If i have the button outside this block it works.

Is there any way to make it work inside to `content_for` block? i need it to be in  the side bar.

Picture of desired result:[image]

Any tips, answers or helpful comments are appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer my self.

By putting the form elements into the sidebar rails of course rendered the form field outside the form tag. (at the bottom of the page where the rest of the sidebar is rendered through the application layout).

This causes the form field to be unattached to the form.

My solution was to drop the `content_for` block and just handeling the sidebar in the form partial for this case.